# How to compare two tables and find the differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, compare

I have two tables like below. I am using SQL DB.

Table1:

```
Id Name
1  leo
2  lin
3  kim
4  ken
5  jon
6  kelly
```

Table2:

```
Id Name Date
1  leo  2019-04-11
2  lin  2019-04-17
3  kim  2019-02-15
4  ken  2018-04-11
```

I am trying to compare this two table and find out which name in table1 does not have a Date.

I need this output.

Result:

```
Id Name
5  jon
6  kelly
```

Could anyone please help me with this query.

Comment: Please read [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. In code questions give a [mcve]. Show what relevant queries you can do & explain why you are stuck. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. PS "compare two tables", "find the differences" & "find out" are so vague that they don't mean anything. If we told you to do that, you wouldn't know what we mean. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Answer (score 6):

Use a **LEFT JOIN**:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Name = Table2.Name
WHERE Table2.Name is NULL
```

Or you can use **WHERE NOT EXISTS**:

```
SELECT * From Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.Name = Table2.Name)
```

Or you can use **WHERE NOT IN**:

```
SELECT * From Table1
WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
SELECT Id,Name FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT Id,Name FROM Table2
```